# How to access Exchange shared mailbox from Thunderbird, different domains

Tags: thunderbird, imap, shared-mailbox, exchange-2016

I have an email address like **myname@company1.com** and I want to access a shared mailbox **sharedmailbox@company2.com**, where company1 and company2 are just different names at the same server.

I use Thunderbird/Postbox client instead of Outlook due to important religious matters. And everything works fine if the shared mailbox is **@company1.com**. I only need to set:

```
User Name: myname@company1.com\sharedmailbox@company1.com
```

However, working with company2.com like this:

```
User Name: myname@company1.com\sharedmailbox@company2.com
```

does not work at all - the password is not accepted.

How can I work with Exchange's shared mailboxes if the domain names do not match?

Comment: Regarding the thought: does not work; I need to provide "myname" somewhere anyway to use my credentials.

Comment: @fixer1234: Some servers have the concept of 'impersonation' (basically sudo but for email), where you always provide _your own_ credentials and the server verifies that you're allowed to access that other mailbox.

Comment: @fixer1234: I never said it is an alias...

Comment: This is a case where I use my own (myname) credentials to access another mailbox.

Comment: I'll keep an eye on this post for a working answer as **I was never able to get a solution to this between two different domains (not with Thunderbird though) that were setup as two-way trusts**. You can do this all day long with different accounts on the same domain granting appropriate permissions in Exchange to the MB accordingly (full access in my case I believe). Lastly, I was not on Exchange 2016 either so there are some differences in this instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per an answer listed on [How to access a Shared Mailbox using Thunderbird or other IMAP client](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange) you may just need to [define, confirm, or change a unique alias](https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/aliases.htm#Can_I_change_my_default_alias_I_send_with) for the shared mailbox in Exchange 2016 and then use the below syntax rather than what you tried per your question.

`User Name: myname@company1.com\sharedmailbox` (user\shared mailbox **alias**)

> ### [**How to access a Shared Mailbox using Thunderbird or other IMAP client**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange)
>
> **Exchange Configuration**
>
> ```
> USER EMAIL: user@maindomain.com   
> PASSWORD: password
> SHARED MAILBOX: shared@anotherdomain.com      (could also be @domain.com, of course)   
> SHARED MAILBOX ALIAS: shared-mailbox
> ```
>
> **Note:** Please make sure to create the ***UNIQUE alias*** always with
>   the mailbox, because it creates the user ***[alias]@maindomain.com***. In
>   this case ***shared-mailbox@maindomain.com***
>
> ---
>
> **Settings for IMAP Configuration**
>
> ```
> EMAIL ADDRESS: shared@anotherdomain.com (shared mailbox)
> IMAP SERVER: outlook.office365.com   
> SMTP SERVER: smtp.office365.com
> USERNAME: user@maindomain.com\shared-mailbox  (user\shared mailbox alias)   
> PASSWORD: password (user's password)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **SMTP Login Is Different**
>
> ```
> USERNAME: user@maindomain.com  (users email)   
> PASSWORD: password (user's password)
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange)</sub>

Comment: This looks like a thing that may work. Still, it feels more like a workaround rather than a solution. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Problem here is that messages are sent as the user not as the shared mailbox. Doesn't work for some user cases.

Comment: With KDE Kontact I had to set authentication to "NTLM" (or "Clear Text") for this to work as  LOGIN/Plain is not supported here.

Comment: We had to give the incoming user FULL ACCESS rights to the shared email account. This was done within Exchange, not outlook

Answer (score 4):

Just came across this a couple of years later, where the accepted answer did not work for me.

This works with Thunderbird 102.2.2 (IMAP configuration), given that you have permission(*) to access the shared mailbox with your account, say `johndoe@example.com`:

- Username: `mysharedmailbox@example.com`
- Security: **SSL/TLS** with **OAuth2**
  (This is enforced by Microsoft anyway).

Once saved, you'll be prompted with the Microsoft login window.

- Select "Sign in with another account"
- Login as `johndoe@example.com` with your usual password.

(*) *Exchange admin center* - (the shared mailbox) - *Delegate*

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: Doesn't work for us, despite having full access permissions on the shared mailbox. Not sure if it makes a difference, but the shared mailbox is on a subdomain, e.g. `info@mail.example.com`, whereas I'm `user@example.com`. (TB 115.8.0 on Windows 10)